# Passing extra object in RemoteCertificateValidationCallback Delegate

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method MethodA where I will be creating an object.

```
private void MethodA()
{
  MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

  try
  {
    ServicePointManger.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += MethodB;
    // some logic
  }
  catch(Exception ex) 
  {
    // some handling
  }
  finally
  {
    // some logic
    ServicePointManger.ServerCertificateValidationCallback -= MethodB;
  }
}
```

In my MethodB, how do I get/pass the MyObject.

```
private bool MethodB(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
{
  // Need MyObject here
}
```

Is there any correct approach fo this?

Comment: For a start, the docs ay *"We don't recommend that you use the `ServicePointManager` class for new development. Instead, use the `HttpClient` class."* And this code makes no sense. You both add and remove the callback with no other code, so it's not actually going to do anything. Be that as it may, you can just use [a lambda with a captured variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions).

Answer (score 0):

By using Lambda.

```
private void MethodA()
{
  MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

  try
  {
    ServicePointManger.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => MethodB(sender, myObject);
    // some logic
  }
  catch(Exception ex) 
  {
    // some handling
  }
  finally
  {
    // some logic
    ServicePointManger.ServerCertificateValidationCallback -= (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => MethodB(sender, myObject);
  }
}

private bool MethodB(object sender, MyObject myObject)
{
  // You have your MyObject here
}
```